# How to store a list of string in setting variables?

Tags: qt

I want to store list of strings, but I got an error.

> C2338 Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro
> to make it known to Qt's meta-object system

I guess I'm wrong about how to use `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators()`...

```
QSettings settings;

qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<const char *>>("QList<const char *>");
settings.setValue("foo", QVariant::fromValue(QList{ "a", "b", "c" }));

auto list = settings.value("foo").value<QList<const char *>>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a list of strings then you must use [`QStringList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html).